# svn server settings - no access allowed

Tags: svn, version-control, svnserve

Sorry for the beginner question. I am trying to set up a SVN server for the first time.

I have the server running but every time I try to checkout I get an error:

> No access allowed to this repository

I was able to checkout when I set anon-access to read, but I always want authentication. Here are my config files:

**svnserve.conf**

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = rw
password-db = /home/svn/Blocks/conf/passwd
realm = Team
```

**passwd**

```
[users]
user = mypass
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Where is your repository? Which URL you're trying to check out? `ls -l /home/svn/Blocks/conf/passwd`?

Comment: Try: auth-access = write

Comment: I am trying the command:
svn co svn://<ip address of server>

the ls -l shows the following:
-rw------- 1 www-data subversion 24 2011-10-12 20:16 /home/svn/Blocks/conf/passwd

I also changed the auth access to write but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the auth-access options available are:

1. none
2. read
3. write

There is no rw option, then try to update your svnserve.conf with auth-access write option.

Comment: I changed the auth-access to write but still no luck. Is there anything else I could check?

Comment: The repository was created with svnadmin comman? And what is the command that you use for launch your server?